# How to delete feature from ArcGIS secured REST end in Android

Tags: arcgis-10.2, arcgis-rest-api, arcgis-android

I am trying to delete feature from secured ArcGIS feature layer using apply edits by passing a graphic array as input, but it is showing me the error

> unable to complete operation, no adds, updates or deletes were specified.

Also, if I  pass the same graphic for update operation then it is being updated successfully.

Following is the code snippet:

```
Map<String, Object> graphicAttributes = new HashMap<String, Object>();  
graphicAttributes.put("OBJECTID", 65);  

Graphic mfinalGraphic = new Graphic(null, null, graphicAttributes);  



arcGISFeatureLayer.applyEdits(null, new Graphic[]{mfinalGraphic}, null, 
     new CallbackListener<FeatureEditResult[][]>() {  
         @Override  
         public void onCallback(final FeatureEditResult[][] featureEditResults) {  

             runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {  
             @Override  
             public void run() {  
                  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Successfully deleted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
             }  
        } );  
  }   

@Override  
public void onError(final Throwable throwable) {  
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {  
@Override  
public void run() {  
  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failed to delete", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
  }  
  });  
  }  
});
```

While tracking on fiddler, I am getting the following request:

> f=json&deletes=&token=BY26ICX0-KN....

The problem is at rest end if I pass only the object id in f=json&deletes=7&token=BY26ICX0-KN.... then it is getting deleted successfully.
But there is no way of passing only object id in applyEdits for delete part in Android API. As `applyEdits` expects only Graphics.